# How to set Position of alert messege in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "JavaScript:alert('MY Message')", true);
```

Above code shows message box on top of the page , but I want it to the center of the page.

Comment: In case you're using latest version of chrome, they override the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Alert boxes by default open at the center. Look at @Tomzan's comment, you are probably getting it at the top for just Chrome.

As far as I know it's not possible to make any modifications to that. If you want a custom alert box look into using jQuery ui. It'll allow you to put a messagebox wherever you want.

[jQuery ui dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 1):

The alert('message') is dialog box shown by browser, with very little to no control over its positioning.

Instead you can use jquery ui dialog to show your message. There are 'n' number of jquery plugins which are available to show the alert messages.
And of course you can control the positioning dialogs of these custom dialogs.

1. http://jqueryui.com/dialog/
2. http://needim.github.io/noty/
3. http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/alert-box